# Joomla 3, Virtuemart 3, Javascript - Uncaught typeerror (...).apply is not a function (only in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, virtuemart

i am working on a shop template for virtuemart 3. its working without error in edge, firefox and internet explorer, but in chrome it (only) sometimes fires an error (at least i couldnt reproduce that error on other browsers).
the error is produced when changing the product variant with the select boxes. most times in product detail, but sometimes on frontpage category view too.

The full error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: ((m.event.special[e.origType] || (intermediate
>   value)).handle || e.handler).apply is not a function

Below is a screenshot from the chrome dev tools.

If someone has a clue, how to solve that or how to catch the error i would be very thankful ;)

or if anyone knows a way to debug and hold the function only when the select-box fires change, it would also help. i can put a breakpoint there, but i fires on mouseenter and other events to, so i never get to click and change the selected value and can inspect the objects when not firing and error.

thx jesta

[image: Error Screen]

[image: Error Screen un-minified]

Comment: Did you try using an un-minified version of jquery and see where it is coming from? Then probably, it could be much clearer.

Comment: i know overrode the jquery to use the un-minified...it still stops at the same line.

Comment: Great! could you put the error screenshot? Can you see what function it errors on? Because, this should much clearer as its un-min.

Comment: is in, its still called jquery.min cause i made a template override for it, so i can easily delete it afterwards

Comment: Joomla und VM both up to date

http://bp-gerd-test.pachlerschatek.at/index.php/new-fruchtsaft-erdbeer-pago-0,75liter-detail

Comment: edit: i deactivated the chosen-jquery in vm, didnt change, it seems to get more buggy then

Comment: so...i deactivated the "use vm jquery" and activated "use extern google programm library" and then did the wild-test-clicking and for now there was no error thrown.